# Creating a shortcut for a function on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, format

I have a data set in which I am applying the `FORMAT` function to add percentages and currency symbols to certain columns. This is extremely repetitive if I have to apply the same function repeatedly with different columns.

For example I have:

```
FORMAT(SUM(Column1),'P'),
FORMAT(....),
FORMAT(SUM(Column10,'P'),
FORMAT(SUM(Column11,'C','en-GB'),
FORMAT(....),
FORMAT(SUM(Column20,'C','en-GB),
```

What I require is a method in which I can apply this FORMAT function to several columns in one go.

i.e. Apply the Format Function to several columns in one go. So the above code would be:

> ```
> FORMAT(
>        (SUM(Column1),'P'),
>            ..... ,
>        (SUM(Column10),'P'),
> FORMAT(
>        (SUM(Column11),'C','en-GB'),
>            ..... ,
>        (SUM(Column20),'C','en-GB'),
> ```

Or if you have any other solution which cleans up the code.

Comment: This is really something for your presentation layer, not the data engine. Especially as `FORMAT` is such a horribly slow performing function. Many design tools allow you to select multiple objects and change their format property.

Comment: What @Larnu saying is correct. But can you be more specific in asking the question so that we can understand.

Comment: There is nothing built in to SQL server to facilitate this, and requests for third party tool recommendations are off-topic for SO.

Comment: It appears you need either a view or computed columns. Given your use of SUM, computed columns are not possible.

Comment: Edited my question to clear up what I am asking @Jack

Comment: `FORMAT` returns a scalar value; you can't effect a column set with it. No functions, in SQL Server, effect column sets; they either effect a scalar expression or a **row** set.

Comment: I see. Is there any method to somewhat define your own function so in R it would be: Currency_Function <- function(column){format(column,'C','en-GB') and then Currency_Function(Column1) would result in what i'm after.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to repeat my comment here, as this is my true opinion on the matter still:

> This is really something for your presentation layer, not the data engine. Especially as `FORMAT` is such a horribly slow performing function. Many design tools allow you to select multiple objects and change their format property.

Anyway, if you want to apply the same function, you could hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and then insert the same text on multiple lines, resulting in something like this:

[image]

Comment: Love the animation!